# Update table mysql create with cookie name

Tags: c#, mysql, cookies

My project in c# create a temporary table for single user authentication with username and cookie memorized.

Now I need update this temporary table mysql create with cookie name, but I have this error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1010: Newline in constant
```

What's wrong?

My code below.

```
private void UpdateProduct(string productID)
{
    string sql = String.Format(@"Update `tbl_" + Request.Cookies["userName"].Value + "`
                                set Product = 1 
                                where ID = {0}",
                                    productID);

    using (OdbcConnection cn =
        new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQL"].ConnectionString))
    {
        cn.Open();
        using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, cn))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your

```
"`
set Product = 1 
where ID = {0}"
```

part still needs to be a verbatim string literal since it is a multiline string. Change it like;

```
string sql = String.Format(@"Update `tbl_" + Request.Cookies["userName"].Value + @"`
                            set Product = 1 
                            where ID = {0}",
                            productID);
```

And I don't think you need to use grave accent characters for your table name since it is not a keyword or something.

By the way, since you take your table as an input I strongly suggest you do a strong validation before you put it in your sql or create a whitelist. But, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.